# PHP Datepicker Chrome specific error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a From->to selector use of datepicker which goes through som .ajax code and then loads a Google Line chart.

My problem is that, in Chrome, when the button is clicked and the script has run through one time, the input fields "from" and "to" won't show the datepicker when clicked.

And as stated, this is only in Chrome, in IE and Firefox the input fields will show the Datepicker-popups all the time.

This is my index.php Javascript code for Datepicker:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="js">

 $(document).ready(function() {

    var dates = $("#from, #to").live('focus', function() { 
        $(this).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        beforeShow: function( ) {
            var other = this.id == "from" ? "#to" : "#from";
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "maxDate" : "minDate";
            var selectedDate = $(other).datepicker('getDate');

            $(this).datepicker( "option", option, selectedDate );
        }
    })
            .change(function(){

                var other = this.id == "from" ? "#to" : "#from";

                if ( $('#from').datepicker('getDate') > $('#to').datepicker('getDate') )
                    $(other).datepicker('setDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate') );

        });
    }); 
});

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {


            var from = $("#from").val();

            var to = $("#to").val();


            $('#box1Res , #box2Res, #box3Res').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />'); // placeholder

            $.ajax( {
                url : 'getjson.php',
                type : 'post',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {tid1: from, tid2: to},               
                success : function( data ) {

                    $('#box1Res').html($('#inner_1' , data).html());
                    $('#box2Res').html($('#inner_2' , data).html());
                    $('#box3Res').html($('#inner_3' , data).html());

                    var test =  ($('#graph_4' , data).html());   
                    $('#chart_div').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');


                            $("#chart_div").load("", function(event){

                            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(test);

                            var options = {
                                    width: 'auto',
                                    height: '200',
                                      title: 'Sales'
                                    };

                            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                            chart.draw(data, options);

                            }); 
                }

            });
               return false;

        });

    });


</script>
```

I have located the code where something is not right;
If i remove this piece of code which .load the chart, the Datepicker will work after the script:

```
$("#chart_div").load("", function(event){

                            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(test);

                            var options = {
                                    width: 'auto',
                                    height: '200',
                                      title: 'Sales'
                                    };

                            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                            chart.draw(data, options);

                            });
```

I'm really out of ideas here, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just noticed that if I click fast in the input field, while the #chart_div is still loading, I see the Datepicker... but then gone.

Comment: Could you post relevant html part ? If possible add a jsFiddle, so we can solve this ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to have solved the issue myself by replacing the line:

```
$("#chart_div").load("", function(event){
```

With:

```
$("#chart_div").ready(function(event){
```

Altough I don't know exactly why this is...?

Anyway, now it works in Chrome...but I have seemed to lost the loading ajax spinner, how can I get it back?
The below line won't work anymore:

```
$('#chart_div').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
```